# SoundCloud JS Authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth, callback, soundcloud

Ok so i've been pulling my hair out for 2 days over this no doubt simple problem.

I'm using their JS SDK, I have created an app, hosted the callback html file, both redirect_uri fields are correctly populated. When I then call the SC.connect the popup loads, I accept permission... then nothing happens. The popup never closes and my authentication is not returned to the original page. I have done everything as they have said in their developer docs. I have checked out their demo pages which work, I have analysed the code, I have even copied to code exactly and run it on my site, same damn problem. Only thing I can think is that it has something to do with the callback.html file. Am I supposed to put code in there to return back to my site after auth? (if so they kept quiet about this in the docs) I checked out the soundcloud version of the callback.html file, there's contains nothing but a link to the sdk.js file? Which I even tried but no matter what I do I can't seem to get the popup to close after auth.

Any ideas guys?

And yes, I'm fairly new to using apis

Comment: If i'm right after opening popup and connecting to soundclound with your credentials access_token saved to your SC object, and after that you can send request to soundcloud api with SC.get(), SC.put() etc. Look to this example i think it help to understand logic http://connect.soundcloud.com/examples/connecting.html

Answer (score 0):

In Soundcloud's sample callback.html, the code:

```
<body onload="window.opener.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

must be altered to:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(window.opener.SC.connectCallback, 1)">
```

This allows the popup to close properly and completes the login flow for the client side javascript SDK. Application settings must be correctly configured to the same domain (localhost or production, but not a mix of the two).

Comment: Apologies for the extremely late reply... Thanks for your input.